# DateTime Warning When Fetching Data From Oracle

Tags: datetime, bdc, oracle

I have an table, which includes DateTime but DateTime makes warning.ıThe warning always saysy that it assumes it UTC. In DateTime typed value there is just date, not included hours.

Why DateTime makes problem? How can I solve it?

Here is how I get the DateTime typed value from the Oracle DB.

```
 entity1.BIRTHDAY_DATE= DateTime.Parse( oReader.GetValue(oReader.GetOrdinal("BIRTHDAY_DATE")).ToString());
```

I tried to put this code with value UTC,Local and Unspecified. Nothing changed.

```
<Interpretation>
      <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />
</Interpretation>
```

My code(Warning appears in ExecuteReader):

```
   try
   {
       entList = new List<Entity1>();
       OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT  * FROM TABLE", oConn);
       oConn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       using (OracleDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (oReader.Read())
           {
                  entity1.STARTWORKDAY= DateTime.Parse(oReader.GetValue(oReader.GetOrdinal("STARTWORKDAY")).ToString());
                  entity1.ID= oReader.GetValue(oReader.GetOrdinal("ID")).ToString();
                  entity1.NAME= oReader.GetValue(oReader.GetOrdinal("NAME")).ToString();
                  entity1.BIRTHDAY=DateTime.Parse(oReader.GetValue(oReader.GetOrdinal("BIRTHDAY")).ToString());
                 **Some other codes**
           }
    }
     }
    catch (Exception ex){}
```

**ABOUT WARNING**
When I try to look the scripts with toad it gives me this error:

> ORA-06550: satır 8, sütun 19:
>   PLS-00553: karakter kümesi adı tanınmıyor
>   ORA-06550: satır 0, sütun 0:
>   PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated

I have searched about this error but I think it's about the processor,I couldn't find any solution.

In Visual Studio it also gives another warning:

> Warning   1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.   CalisanBilgi

Comment: have you used <Interpretation>
      <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />
</Interpretation> on evrey date time fields?

Comment: that's strange since I had the same problem and using NormalizeDateTime worked for me.

Comment: When I debug,It says not valid month. My date columns is like 03.09.2012

Comment: having this warning affects your code in any way? if not then leave it as is.

Comment: I add the code where the warning appears.

Comment: @e.ozmen, If `BIRTHDAY_DATE` is of type `DATE` in the DB (and not a string) then it always contains a time part and it never contains a format, it's just a number representing the date and time. Are you sure it's not a `VARCHAR2` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I looked data types with Toad. It says DATE.

Comment: Can you dump the rowid for the rows where you encounter the problem and then use the dump command in sqlplus to dump the raw column contents for the offending rows.